# What is a UnmodifiableClassException?

Tags: java

I've worked on some code recently, and the compiler throws a `java.lang.UnmodifiableClassException` If someone could explain what it is, how to fix it, and if there are tools available to find one, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compiler doesn't throw exceptions. It generate compile errors. Exceptions are thrown at runtime. Also, there is no `java.lang.UnmodifiableClassException`. Did you mean [`java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/UnmodifiableClassException.html)?

Comment: Compiler could malfunction and throw that, but without more  information we can't really say.

Comment: The basic information is in the Javadocs.  How this applies to your use-case?  We haven't a clue ... because you haven't bothered to describe it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException` description from JavaDoc:

> Thrown by an implementation of [`Instrumentation.redefineClasses`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses(java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...)) when
>   one of the specified classes cannot be modified.

So if you will try to redefine class which forbidden to redefine, you will get this exception `java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException`.

Information about [`Instrumentation.redefineClasses`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses(java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...)) method from JavaDoc:

> Throws `UnmodifiableClassException` - if a specified class cannot be modified
>   (`isModifiableClass(java.lang.Class<?>`) would return false)

Information about [`isModifiableClass(Class<?> theClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#isModifiableClass(java.lang.Class)) method from JavaDoc:

> Determines whether a class is modifiable by retransformation or
>   redefinition. If a class is modifiable then this method returns true.
>   If a class is not modifiable then this method returns false. For a
>   class to be retransformed, `isRetransformClassesSupported()` must also
>   be true. But the value of `isRetransformClassesSupported()` does not
>   influence the value returned by this function. For a class to be
>   redefined, `isRedefineClassesSupported()` must also be true. But the
>   value of `isRedefineClassesSupported()` does not influence the value
>   returned by this function.
>
> Primitive classes (for example, `java.lang.Integer.TYPE`) and array
>   classes are never modifiable.

Comment: I was running Java 7. I updated to java 8 and it changed the error and used the information you gave me to get it to compile and run. Thanks so much for the help!